Advice Regarding KDE Partition Manager and encryption of external HDD
I am using KDE and have created an encrypted luks 1 ext4 partition on my external HDD.
These are the steps that I followed.

Backed up my data;
Cleared the HDD;
Created new encrypted partition (selected ext4 and the option to encrypt the partition using luks - did not toggle luks 2), and;
set my passphrase.

I have tested that I can log in and access the files I put in my encrypted partition.
I can also log in to a live environment and after entering my passphrase I can access my data.
Although I feel, I have taken all the precautions, I still thought I should confirm with the community.
Am I somehow messing up? Missing something? Can I take any more precautions, to not lose my data?
One particular source of anxiety is that when I was researching how to do encryption, I came across a post (that I can't find anymore) where the person lost all their data, even after knowing the passphrase because they didn't have the headerfile.
Now this was an old post and they did a manual set-up (I think), I have verified that I can access my drive from a live environment but still, could I ever end up in a similar situation, or any other possible situation leading me to do not access my data?
Sorry for a rather amateurish question. I just wanted some opinions from people who have done this before.
Cheers.

You've not provided release details for your Kubuntu, thus we don't know what software stack and installer you're asking about. Kubuntu defaults vary on release, and you've not given release detail (KDE Partition Manager will work on both, but release matters where LUKS in involved; esp. in regards install)

Hello, what information can I provide? Please do tell

What Ubuntu release are you using? What release of Kubuntu.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.
Assuming you’re asking about protecting against losing the data (as opposed to a security breach of someone stealing it), yes, you are missing something fundamental.
What you’ve done looks fine.
However, you should always assume you can - and probably will at some point - lose that data. The only way to protect against that is to have reliable backups (contemporaneous, multiple, automatic, separate physical location, reliably accessed when needed).
It might seem peripheral to what you’re asking, but failures do happen: you leave the external drive on a train, someone steals it, hardware fails, you mess up and overwrite critical data, etc. etc.

Hello thanks for the reply, Yes I did backup, However my question is after what I have done (assuming no damages, me forgetting the password etc) this drive will behave like a encrypted external hdd and will work with all linux systems as long as I know the password. Ie if I change my OS I can still mount this drive or if there is an update and I update to the next version this drive would still be accessible?
